# Nextjs first load isnt loading the css properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Issue with the first load of the mobile app version; for some reason, the CSS of my component that encompasses the page is not loaded on the initial screen load. However, when changing the size to desktop and then switching back to mobile, it displays correctly. I noticed that by altering the ID "__next," it ensures that the styles I want to retain stay on the page. However, the logic to check if the screen size is that of a mobile to display another icon is not functioning. Below are some images for reference:

##### without __next fix

[image]

##### with __next fix

[image]

##### resize from desktop without fix

[image]

### _document.tsx

```js
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-sync-scripts */
import React from 'react'
import Document, { Html, Main, NextScript, Head, DocumentContext } from 'next/document'

class CustomDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="pt-br" id="html">
        <Head>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"/>
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/favicon-16x16.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon/favicon.ico" />
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/react-github-contribution-calendar/default.css" type="text/css" />
          <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1e2ddc5739.js"></script>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default CustomDocument
```

### _app.tsx

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import { AuthProvider } from '../utils/contexts/AuthContext';
import GlobalStyle from '@/components/ui/styles/globalStyles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { createEmotionCache } from '@/utils/createEmotionCache';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { ModalProvider } from '@/utils/contexts/ModalContext';
import { ptBR } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/locales';
import { pt } from 'date-fns/locale'
import { RecoilRoot } from 'recoil';

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

interface CustomAppProps {
  Component: any;
  pageProps: any;
  emotionCache: any;
}

const App = ({ Component, pageProps, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache }: CustomAppProps) => {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page: any) => page);
  const locale = ptBR.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText;
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <AuthProvider>
        <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} localeText={locale} adapterLocale={pt}>
            <ModalProvider>
              <Head>
                <title>
                  Blakbelt
                </title>
                <meta
                  name="viewport"
                  content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
                />
              </Head>
              <CssBaseline />
              <GlobalStyle />
              <ToastContainer />
              {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
            </ModalProvider>
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: when you start the app, do you see this metatag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`  if you check the chrome tools

Answer (score 0):

If you are using global styles, make sure your they are compatible with SSR. If there are specific styles that should only be applied client-side, consider using next/dynamic to load them dynamically.

Example:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ClientOnlyStyles = dynamic(() =>
  import ('../path/to/client-only-styles.css'), {
    ssr: false,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code in the Component file.

```
<style jsx>{`
//style description
`}
</style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).